# jQuery Autocomplete only works for the first time

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a web application. This is my code:

```
var data=["New York","Los Angeles","Chicago","Seattle"];
$(function(){
  $( "#title" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term ), "i" );
      response( $.grep( data, function( item ){
        return matcher.test( item );
      }) );
    }
  }); 
});
```

Problem with this code is that autocomplete gives suggestions only for the first time. If we type anything in the search bar after that, it does not give suggestions.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine multiple times: https://jsfiddle.net/rc92o7sj/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Works fine multiple times for me too (IE 11).

Comment: LOL I wish I had checked the comments because I also tried to answer -
 is it possible that you don't have the the correct/matching versions of jquery/jqueryui?   https://jsfiddle.net/hanleybrand/qwt0kh2t/

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Figured out that another piece of code was preventing it from being populated again.